# Applying Custom Function to Data.Table

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I need to apply a custom function to all rows in a data.table which has columns freq (numeric), ngram (text with each word separated by _).  I also supply 3 values which are constant - input1gramCount, input2gramCount, input3gramCount and not in the data.table.

When I try this, i get the warning

```
Warning message:
In if (MatchedLen == 4) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

It seems to be complaining that 4 is not vectorised, but I want it to be a constant.  Any pointers welcome...

```
# Stupid Backoff
StupidBackoffScore <- function(freq, ngram, input1gramCount, input2gramCount, input3gramCount) {
    matchedLen = str_count(ngram, "_") + 1
    if (matchedLen == 4) {
        score = freq / input3gramCount
    } else if (matchedLen == 3) {
        score = 0.4 * freq / input2gramCount
    } else {
        # must be matchedLen 2
        score = 0.4 * 0.4 * freq / input1gramCount
    }
    return(score)
    }

allGrams <- allGrams %>%
    mutate(stupidBOScore = StupidBackoffScore(frequency, ngram, input1gramCount, input2gramCount, input3gramCount))
```

Comment: It's complaining that "if" is not vectorised, a warning from base R. You could use `first(matchedLen) == 4` instead if the value is constant. (dplyr and data.table both have a first function)

Comment: Its the 4 thats's constant, not matchedLen

Comment: Ok. In that case, you need to rewrite the program taking into account that "if" is for single conditions (for "control flow" rather than vectorized calculations). Alternately, maybe look at applying the function rowwise with purrr or similar (though that will be very inefficient).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
setDT(dt)
dt[, matchedLen := str_count(ngram, "_") + 1 ]
dt[, score := ifelse(matchedLen == 4, freq / input3gramCount,
                     ifelse(matchedLen == 3, 0.4 * freq / input2gramCount,
                        0.4 * 0.4 * freq / input1gramCount)) ]
```

For readability, I created `matchedLen` as a separate column. If you do not need `matchedLen` you can delete it after the score is created.

Comment: Thanks and also to @Frank.  I had solved it with Frank's input switching to if else and then found case_when - the trick was realising I couldn't use if.  Map's design is good as it does it directly with the data.frame.